# ETag not received after changing get Request Parameters

Tags: java, http-headers, etag

I am trying to track a unique ID using ETags.

I have a java spring controller deployed - localhost:8080/testTag/hitApi.html

Issue is that i am receiving two different ETags for below two requests. The only difference is in get query parameters -

> get Request 1 - localhost:8080/testTag/hitApi.html?**name=user1**&id=123
>
> get Request 2 -localhost:8080/testTag/hitApi.html?**name=user2**&id=123

is this the normal behavior in case of ETags?

Can I get same ETag for two requests above?

Thanks and Regards,
Vibhav

Answer (score 0):

ETag value is based on the content on the response http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.html

Comment: That I understand that i have to compare incoming ETag and generated ETag. My problem is that I am not receiving same ETag with change in request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Etag value shows the state of the resource in question, in your case resource pointed out by *name=user1&id=123* , if the resource you need has  changed so should the ETag value , Assuming that you have figured out how to generate (based on the last Updated time of the resource or some other schema ), the Etag received must be same